# UIButton is not working/Clickable in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, storyboard, autolayout

I am using auto layout with `UIScrollView`.

Main `UIView` Height = 1300

ContentView (within `UIScrollBar`) `UIView` = 1100

The ConetntView contains a button at the bottom. It is completely visible but when I click it, it does not work.

Constraints are :

1) `ScrollView` leading, trailing, top & bottom with main `UIView`

2) `ContantView` leading, trailing, top & bottom with `UIScrollView`

3) Equal height constraint between `ContentView` & main `UIView`

Please help.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that scroll view's content view height is less than `UIScrollView`'s height? Also, to find out if autolayout is root cause of this issue, I'd set 'clip subviews' property of a button's parent view to YES. If the problem is caused by layout then the button won't be visible anymore.

Comment: Button's parent view means ContentView which is enclosed within the UIScrollView in my case. Ok...I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes you are right. After setting clip subview of the button's parent (ConetntView), button and a few other child view are not appearing. Instead white blank area is appearing. Pls help.

Comment: @"Did I understand correctly that scroll view's content view height is less than UIScrollView's height?" 
UIScrollView Height: 1160
ContentView UIView (nested within UIScrollView) Height:1315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to provide (-)ve value for bottom space of the ContentView from the superview. It did the job. Initially it was set to zero and because of this there was a large extra space below the bottom and it made the scrolling larger that was not desired.

I have tested it in all the simulators - 4s to 6+ and it is working fine.

Thanks to Nikolay for his continuous help.

Also as I am completely new to iPhone development so I do not know whether my workaround is correct or not. So if there is another solution to the problem then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820304/uibutton-is-not-working-clickable-in-uiscrollview?noredirect=1#comment44071555_27820304) this is layout issue. I think root cause is 3rd constraint. Please remove it and create another constraint for Content View Height with hardcoded height value (like 'Height - (1315) - Content View'). If you need to have flexible height for Content View, i.e. not hardcoded in the Storyboard, then please modify it programmatically.

Comment: Ok ..that works...and I also tried this yesterday. But the problem with this approach is that there is a large white background area appears below the button. And this makes the scrolling are larger that required. Pls help.

Comment: Please help somebody.

Comment: Can you please share screenshots of the issue and screenshot of your storyboard with constraints? You can configure constraints so that there will be no any extra spaces. But it's hard to help you without seeing of what's wrong with your constraints.

Comment: It is hard to send you snapshot..for security reason. sorry :(

Comment: @TishaAnand, can you please upvote my answer if it was useful for you?