# UIButton in a scrollView is not responding

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a ScrollView, and a container view inside of it. 
UIButtons are inside of the container view. 
When I run the program, `UIButtons` that are at the end of the ScrollView are unresponsive.
UITextFields are responsive.
Yet, after tweaking around with frames I made sure that both origin and hightXwidth of UIScrollView and container view are matched. I checked it with print statements.
Some of the settings:

```
scrollView.isExclusiveTouch = true
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

ScrollView's content size:

```
let hightForScrollMenu: CGFloat = 120
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height+hightForScrollMenu)
```

Output view:
[image]

When checking:

```
viewInsideScrollView.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height
print("Zhenya: ScrollView's frame height is:\(scrollView.frame.size.height) and its origin is \(scrollView.frame.origin)")
print("Zhenya: ViewInsideScrollView's frame heigt is: \(viewInsideScrollView.frame.size.height) and its origin is \(scrollView.frame.origin)")
```

[image]

View Controller attributes:

[image]

Main View attributes and constraints:

[image]

[image]

ScrollView attributes and constraints:

[image]

[image]

Container View attributes and constraints:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [FistLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132147/uibutton-inside-uiscrollview-doesnt-fire-on-tap), 
[SecondLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649639/uibutton-does-not-work-when-it-in-uiscrollview), 
[ThirdLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820304/uibutton-is-not-working-clickable-in-uiscrollview)

Comment: thanks. Tried those before posting this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was - to set container's view hight to 616. 
I don't understand why setting its hight to "equal to ScrollView" or fixing it programmatically to equal scrollView's didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The Container View is the red view? Well, then obviously the button is outside it. A button outside its superview is untappable.

Comment: Yes, the ContainerView is the red view. And it does look like the button is outside of it. However, in the view structure that button is part of the container view. And all of its constraints are connected to container view.

Comment: I don't care about "look like" (though it was helpful of you to color the views). I don't care about "part of" and "connected to". The red clearly shows that the button _is_ outside of is superview. That makes the button impossible to tap. End of story. Your question is answered. Your question was "the button is not responding". I've told you why. Correctly.